# Do Valorous Commendations ignore the Valor Point cap?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Since the release of the Mists of Pandaria for World of Warcraft, the valor point cap per week has been adjusted to 1000 valor points per week.

For one of the daily quests for the Order of the Cloud Serpents you can earn valor points for competing in a race on your cloud serpent;

[image: Valorous Commendation]

I am already valor capped this week, does using this item still give me 15 valor points (thus ignoring the cap) or are they wasted because I am over the valor point cap already?

Comment: I thought the cap was there in Cata? It's the maximum cap that has been adjusted to 3000 from 4000. The weekly cap never changed.

Comment: The maximum valor cap was changed, but the weekly cap is now 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your weekly valor points cap applies to everything. It doesn't matter what the source of the valor points is, be it from items, dailies, scenarios, dungeons or raids.

The game *will* allow you to use this item, even if you are capped. It just won't give you the indicated amount.

The best way to do this is to wait till just before the cap resets to hand in the [quest](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=30152).

Comment: To clarify, wait until the reset before even opening the bag that the item comes out of. Once the item is out of the bag, it will only last for an hour.